# Mule ESB set OutputStream to MessageContext as payload

Tags: java, mule, esb

I have a custom HTTP Connector as a seperate spring bean. It's calling remote server which return video streams. Connector gets message object for input parameter and baseURL:

```
public class MediaArchiveHttpConnector {    

    public void processHttpRequest(Object message, String baseURL)
            throws IOException {
...
MessageContext ctx = (MessageContext) message;
...
```

Now I'm calling remote endpoint with Apache HttpClient lib:

```
...
response = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
...
ctx.setPayload(EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity));
```

And unfortunatelly get an OutOfMemoryError on files more than few hundreads of megabytes because implementation of Apache HttpClient lib stores all the stream in RAM

Is it possible to forward stream directly to client without processing it like:

```
ctx.setPayload(outputStream);
```

? 
Or any other ideas to avoid stream buffering inside Mule and forward all data to client?

Answer (score 0):

That is quite an httpClient question rather than a Mule question.

I do not recommend to to yourself work that Mule actually does for you. Try to leave that work to an http:outbound-endpoint and it will take care of the streaming mode for you.

If you really need performance, you could also try the new Mule 3.6 that includes a new http connector much more performant that the old one based in httpclient.

Comment: Thx. I wrote custom http conntector because mule http connector doesn't support transparrent work with cookies and headers, sessions and multiple users. It's critical for me.

Comment: For most if not all of the usecases Mule can handle cookies, headers, senssions and auth. Perhaps you can break down your problems in different questions.